# How to configure a logging interceptor for all registered type in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-container, aop, ioc-container

I am going to trace every actions happened in the services which are managed by the Unity Container as logs in file system. I suppose I could define an interface named IService and all the other interfaces or implementation should inherit from him. On the other hand, I would like to develop a custom interception behavior or call handler to save the logs into files.

Unfortunately, I found that it doesn't work for me by using this codes

```
IUnityContainer unity = new UnityContainer();

//Interception
unity.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
Interception interception = unity.Configure<Interception>();
unity.RegisterType<IService>(
    new DefaultInterceptor(new InterfaceInterceptor()),
    new DefaultInterceptionBehavior(new LoggingBehavior()));

string[] configFiles = Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.config");
foreach (string configFile in configFiles)
{
    var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = configFile };
    System.Configuration.Configuration configuration =
        ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap,  
        ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    var unitySection = (UnityConfigurationSection)
        configuration.GetSection("unity");
    unity = unitySection.Configure(unity);
}

IGateway imapGW = unity.Resolve<IGateway>("ImapGateway");
```

Is there any misunderstanding for me to use interceptor in Unity? How can I deal with this issue to log everything automatically without configuring interceptor for each service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to implement the logger. Long time ago I wrote an article about how to set up interceptors:

http://hmadrigal.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/aspect-oriented-programming-and-interceptor-design-pattern-with-unity-2/

For logging you could use Debug.Write, and configure TraceListeners. Or also you could Use Enterprise Library or any third party log library.

Kind regards,
Herber